# Remotely getting all the tab names of a given excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tabs

I am trying to build a Spreadsheet tool that can quickly pull selected data from other spreadsheets, allowing me to check for bad values or errors on a multitude of spreadsheets each of which will have 40+ tabs. I have been successful in programming my spreadsheet exclusively with "in cell" Excel functions to

1 Identify the target spreadsheet (this should be the only user input)

2 pull the values from a series of selected cells on the target spreadsheet across multiple tabs.

The problem is that while =indirect and =concatenate have allowed me to build a functioning system, if anyone modifies the template by a single row or column, the tool breaks, or at least pulls data from the wrong cell.

So now I'm looking for how to adjust to this. I've found solutions to moving cells using index, match, and offset, I just need everyone to not delete the search term label from the adjacent cell, and that feels reasonable. As long as one and only one cell on the sheet says "Total", I can get the value to the right of that, and that's more than enough.

But now I have the problem "what if they renamed the tabs?" And yes. Yes they did. A lot.

So in order to aim my index and match at the right spot, I need the tab names to concatenate into the indirects, and to get those without twenty minutes of manual labor per spreadsheet I check I need to automatically generate a list of the tab names on the spreadsheet I'm targeting. I need to generate this list without adding macros to the target spreadsheet, keeping it exclusively on my tool.

I realize this may simply be beyond the capacity of excel, and I'm not ready to start coding 80 line macros. But I'm hoping that there is some sort of query or series of nested functions that will remotely list the names of an excel's tabs, and that someone out there knows it.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/list-sheet-names-with-formula maybe?

Comment: I found this too, but it looks like it only works if I install a table tab names on each Spreadsheet, and I don't think I can do that. I'm dealing with literally thousands of such spreadsheets across the company, and they are all subject to modification by their primary users, I as an auditor/controller cannot go modifying everyone's sheet, even if I had the time to do so, even if I could somehow prevent anyone from ever messing with my tables, which I could not. Gotta keep it all on my one spreadsheet tool. Everything has to be remote.

Comment: Ok, then very doable with VBA (won't be 80 lines at all). Simple `For Each` loop.

Comment: @BigBen - for my sake at least - what did you have in mind RE: VBA - including table tab names or doing the extraction itself (or both)?

Comment: @JonEckardt - can you clarify *'modify a column or row'* ?

Comment: @JB-007 - well one could do both for sure, but I was only thinking of listing the sheet names, a la `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, `Dim sheetNames() As String`, `ReDim sheetNames(1 to .Count)`, `Dim i as Long`, `For i = 1 to .Count`, `sheetNames(i) = .Item(i).Name`, `Next`, `End With`... something like that.

Comment: @BigBen - gotcha, ta.

Comment: Do you consider using Power Query on your Excel? I would definitely consider using that to solve this problem.

Comment: To be clear, I have logged precesly zero seconds of VBA. To do it, I'd need a walkthrough. But if there is a thing that I could put on MY spreadsheet that would do this job without counting as "foreign software" such that the company would be mad at me, and if I could contain it within a few cells, and the end result was an auto populating list from any targeted Spreadsheet of that sheet's tab names so's I could then extract them and concatenate them into my searches, resulting in automatically finding the word "totals" or "final sum" or whatever convention we settle on and extracting, great.

Comment: @JB-007 -  These are commonly used spreadsheets, they'll be worked on by at least four people working on each one each month, and it's possible that at any point someone will say "I need an extra column on this page in between widgits and doodads to represent our sprocket capture" or "I have six more buyers for my doodads this month, I'm gonna have to insert some rows." 

And this will displace the cells that I am trying to get, which are disconnected from the other tables on the sheet.

Comment: @BigBen - So I found a VBA walkthrough, I opened it, I copied your code, I saved, I closed the editor... there's nothing there. I have no idea what I'm doing with VBA. Any good tutorials you could recommend?

Comment: `sheetNames()` is an array. If you want to see anything, you have to output it somewhere (which would be a worksheet in your case?). Or what do you mean by "there's nothing there"?

Comment: @JonEckardt - yep - perhaps I expand my Q to ensure we're on same page here - I get/understand the *lot's of workbooks comprising lots of sheets being utilised by several people* bit - I'm chiefly interested in the kinds of edits i.e. the *modify* bit- this can mean a plethora of things - insertions/deletion/cutting from one place putting into another - are you saying *anything/all* kinds of modifications ? (I think you are, but the gp. in question may only be modifying by inserting and know better than to delete - unless this is the practise regularly undertaken..) This may have implications

Comment: @ big ben - When I say there's nothing there I mean that when I input the code and close it, nothing new happens. It is as if I didn't input anything at all. There are no arrays, no outputs, no data, I see nothing useful. I might as well have deleted the code.

Later, I started getting an error message every few minutes. Nothing useful, just telling me that my code didn't do something and had to close. I eventually went into the macro tool and deleted the text, which still produced no output but at least the errors stopped.

Comment: @ JB007 - I beleive that the vast majority of the modifications will be to simply insert rows, however moving things around, adding new areas, and deleting are not off the table. Further, these modifications will be taking place when I and my tool are offline, so I figured I'd treat the whole thing as a black box rather than trying to track and police other people's edits.

Comment: @BigBen - OK, I went back through and poked it repeatedly, and got something of a result. So as I understand it, this Macro has to be activated, then it asks me to specify a Workbook file, and then it generates the output list, creating a table that lists the file path, the sheet name, and shows the range of cells on the sheet. So this is pretty awesome in its own right. Problems I have:
1 the sheet populates on B1, and overwrites what is there. I was using those cells.
2 I don't actually need all of this, can it be trimmed to just names?
3 Can I link the activation to another cell?

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots / code below refer:

---

**VB code:**

*adapted from [Microsoft office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.allowmultiselect) and (chiefly) [Dalgleish, D (2016)](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/excel-macro-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook.htm)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim aWbk As Workbook
    Dim aSh As String
    Dim lcount, lfields As Long
    
    Set aWbk = ActiveWorkbook
    aSh = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    j = -1
    aWbk.Sheets(aSh).Range("B:G").Clear
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select an Excel File"
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx?", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        
        'Dim sFilePaths As Array(String)
    
        If .Show = -1 Then
              lcount = 2
              lfields = 6
            
              With aWbk.Sheets(aSh)
                 .Range(.Cells(1, 2), _
                 .Cells(1, lfields + 1)).Value _
                  = Array( _
                        "File Name", _
                        "Sheet Name", _
                        "Used Range", _
                        "Range Cells", _
                        "Shapes", _
                        "Last Cell")
            End With

            For Each file In .SelectedItems
                Call ListSheetsRangeInfo(file, 3 * j, aWbk, aSh)
            Next

        End If
    End With
    

End Sub


Sub ListSheetsRangeInfo(sTheSourceFile As Variant, j As Integer, aWbk As Workbook, aSh As String)
'https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2016/03/10/list-all-excel-sheets-with-used-range/
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lcount As Long
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim rngF As Range
Dim lfields As Long
Dim strLC As String
Dim strSh As String
Dim sha As Shape
Dim sh As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim src As Workbook
'On Error Resume Next
  
  Set src = Workbooks.Open(sTheSourceFile, False, True)      ' Open the source file.
  lfields = 6
  'lbcount = lcount
  src.Activate
  For Each sh In src.Sheets
      strLC = sh.Cells _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) _
          .Address
      If sh.ProtectContents = True Then
        strSh = ""
      Else
        If sh.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
          strSh = ""
          For Each sha In sh.Shapes
            strSh = strSh & sha.TopLeftCell _
                .Address & ", "
          Next sha
          strSh = Left(strSh, Len(strSh) - 2)
        End If
      End If
      
      With aWbk.Sheets(aSh)
        lcount = .Range("b1:b" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count + 1
        .Range(.Cells(lcount, 2), _
          .Cells(lcount, lfields + 1)).Value _
          = Array( _
              sTheSourceFile, _
              sh.Name, _
              sh.UsedRange.Address, _
              sh.UsedRange.Cells.Count, _
              strSh, _
              strLC)
        'add hyperlink to sheet name
        .Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=.Cells(lcount, 2), _
            Address:=sTheSourceFile, _
            SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name _
                & "'!A1", _
            ScreenTip:=sh.Name, _
            TextToDisplay:=sTheSourceFile
        'add hyperlink to last cell
        .Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=.Cells(lcount, lfields + 1), _
            Address:=sTheSourceFile, _
            SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name _
                & "'!" & strLC, _
            ScreenTip:=strLC, _
            TextToDisplay:=strLC
        
        
      End With
  Next sh
 
With aWbk.Sheets(aSh)
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, lfields + 1)) _
      .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


src.Close False         ' False, so you don't save the source file.
Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

**Mechanics**

Comprises 2 modules:

1. Button1_Click() : to attach to a command button (or can run directly from VBA project explorer) - this module allows you to browse for files of interest (multi-selection possible).  It then calls the next module/program (2), and repeats this step for every file you selected
2. ListSheetsRangeInfo() : retrieves relevant info (used ranges, sheetnames etc) from excel files you selected in module 1 - info returned will be unaffected by whatever modifications users made (it will simply identify the modified range across all existing sheets - customize to allow for hidden sheets as req.).

*You can also override ranges in col D as desired e.g.*

- *remove final row*
- *select desired columns*
- *retrieve all / select used ranges* etc.etc.

You are know able to reference unbroken/robust cell ranges given the entire series of file paths, used ranges constituents of every respective sheet as req. (no broken links and the link due to inserting a column, rows, or even relabelling / creating new or deleting sheet(s) within resp. workbooks).

One way to retrieve, for instance, would be to set up a formula in column A as follows:

```
=IF(B2="","",LET(x_,LEN(B2)-MATCH("\",MID(B2,LEN(B2)-ROW($B$1:OFFSET($B$1,LEN(B2)-1,0,1,1)),1),0),"'"&MID(B2,1,x_)&"["&MID(B2,x_+1,LEN(B2)-x_+4)&"]")&C2&"'!"&D2)
```

*(assumes you have Office 365 compatible version Excel)*

[image: Creating robust range link based upon VB output]

Then continue building the range reference to exernal sheets as follows:

```
="="&A2
```

[image: Creating links step 2]

Copy this and paste special values - which leaves you with an unevaluated external workbook range reference (select, press F2 and return carriage will result output from the external file in question (if the external workbook in Q was not recalculated when last closed, Excel will prob. prompt a dialogue box advising you - just press enter/OK and a #Spill! will return the values desired/specified.

[image: Not recalculated (sample error mesg)]

[image: Sample output]

---

PS - *will just mention: the benefit of this approach is that if someone has unscrupulously included dozens of additional sheets, you'll  be able to screen - and keep your main workbook light-weight/only containing desired info*

---